# Using NSIS, Custom Page Two Question. ListView / NSISList Text

Tags: nsis

Thank you :]

1. When using ListView, Korean is not expressed, but strange characters are displayed. (Photo attached) And some characters are well included in List(NSISList), but some characters are not. I tried adding the source below, but the text didn't show up properly. What sources do I need to add to get the text to look right?
   I am using NSIS 3.x version.

   !ifndef LVM_GETITEMTEXT

   !define /math LVM_GETITEMTEXTA ${LVM_FIRST} + 45

   !define /math LVM_GETITEMTEXTW ${LVM_FIRST} + 115

   ${_NSIS_DEFAW} LVM_GETITEMTEXT

   !endif

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0ef.png)

2. I will express it in Korean. It is used by adding any character to the List. Before adding, if it is displayed as a MessageBox, it comes out well, and the character is added to the List. But when I tried to add it and use it again, the characters were cut off, and even when I printed it to the TextBox, it didn't come out. Based on "대", the characters after it are not stored in the List.

ex) 서대문 = "서", 대구 = ""

```
Function ListTest
 ${List.Create} Aerch
 ${List.Add} Serch "서대문구"
 ${List.Get} $0 Serch 0
 
 MessageBox MB_OK $0
FunctionEnd
; Return $0 = 서
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you have `Unicode True` at the start of your script.
- Make sure you save your script as UTF-8 BOM or UTF-16LE BOM.
- !include nsDialogs before commctrl.nsh
- Make sure you are using the Unicode version of all plug-ins.

Characters that "look Chinese" is a symptom of treating ASCII as UTF-16. Strings cut off after the first character is a symptom of treating UTF-16 as ASCII (not a Unicode plug-in?).

This works for me:

```
Unicode True
RequestExecutionLevel user

!include nsDialogs.nsh
!define _COMMCTRL_NSH_VERBOSE 3
!include commctrl.nsh

Section
SectionEnd
Page custom nsDialogsPage
Var lv


Function msgboxtext
Pop $0
SendMessage $lv ${LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK} 0 0 $8
StrCpy $9 1
${If} $8 = -1 
Return
${EndIf}

System::Call '*(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})p.r3'
System::Call "*(i, i, i, i, i, p, i, i, i) p  (0, 0, $9, 0, 0, r3, ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) .r1"
System::Call "User32::SendMessage(p, i, p, p) p ($lv, ${LVM_GETITEMTEXT}, $8, r1)"
System::Call "*$3(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r4)"
System::Free $1
System::Free $3
MessageBox mb_ok $4
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateButton} 0 0 100% 12u "Get text"
Pop $9
${NSD_OnClick} $9 msgboxtext

nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD ${WC_LISTVIEW} ${__NSD_ListView_STYLE}|${WS_TABSTOP} ${__NSD_ListView_EXSTYLE}  0 13u 100% -13u ""
Pop $lv
${NSD_LV_InsertColumn} $lv 0 100 "column 0"
${NSD_LV_InsertColumn} $lv 1 70 "서대문"

${NSD_LV_InsertItem} $lv 0 '서대문'
${NSD_LV_SetItemText} $lv 0 1 '서대문 서대문'

${NSD_LV_InsertItem} $lv 1 '2 서대문'
${NSD_LV_SetItemText} $lv 1 1 '2.2 서대문 서대문'


nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add command "unicode True" at the top of the script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [@Anders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68771019/3025856) as a good example of the level of detail to provide when answering questions. Note that they cover `Unicode True`, but also a handful of other possible issues, alongside a full set of code that confirms it all works together.